# Migrate 32-bit Firefox settings to 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 64-bit

I've got Windows 7 x64 and would like to start using the latest 64-bit build of Firefox. However, my 32-bit Firefox 3.6.13 has a ton of personal settings. MozBackup would be a good choice, but not sure if it allows imports into the x64 Firefox from the 32-bit.

The x64 FF also needs to run Firebug (doesn't seem to be supported on this version). Anyone know how to do these?

Comment: I would look into if Firefox 32-bit profiles are compatible with 64-bit Firefox. If they are, just backup your profile and paste it back after 64-bit installation.

Comment: There might be an even easier way: If you install the latest FF 4 beta, it comes with the Firefox Sync, which allows your profile to be saved to the FF server. Then you can load it on another "computer" (or version of FF).

Comment: Read the solution here: http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2011/02/moving-to-64-bit-firefox-on-windows-7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know with IE, every plugin has to then be 64bit.  things like Java, Flash, AV software plugins, etc.  We have basically hidden 64bit IE on our business desktops, and only use them to test new features we write work in it.

Similar thing in Office 2010.  MS doesn't even run 64bit in most offices, because every add-in then has to be 64bit.

Comment: Don't believe that's the case with FF. Firebug works well in the 64-bit version and it's the same XPI used to install it for both 32- and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

A program called [Waterfox](http://www.waterfoxproject.org/), developed by Mozilla, is a 64-bit version of Firefox.  All the extensions, bookmarks, and other things are able to easily be transferred extremely easily, even though some or possibly all of them are 32-bit.  When uninstalling Firefox, you will be prompted with a check box to remove all user settings.  Just don't check that box when you uninstall Firefox.  When you install Waterfox, all your settings will auto-magically be imported.  Simple and easy.